# Primefaces editRowEvent is don't work and update

Tags: ajax, spring, primefaces, datatable, edit

My datatable is editable. when I edit the row, comes from the old data but i need new data.

first view: http://blog.kaykisiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/1.png

click edit button : http://blog.kaykisiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/2.png

click accept button: =>firstview

mypage.xhtml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/maintemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">

        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Dosya Adi" />
            <h:outputText value="#{sessionController.messageFile.fileName}" />

            <h:outputText value="Dosya Yolu" />
            <h:outputText value="#{sessionController.messageFile.filePath}" />

        </p:panelGrid>

        <h:form id="formEdit">
            <p:dataTable var="item" 
                value="#{messageFileDetailController.fileDetailList}" id="itemList"
                paginator="true" scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" rows="25"
                resizableColumns="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                scrollHeight="100%" editable="true" editMode="row" >

                <f:facet name="header">Metin Listesi</f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" 
                    listener="#{messageFileDetailController.onRowEdit}" />


                <p:column headerText="Baslik" filterBy="#{item.messageTitle}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.messageTitle}" style="font-weight:bolder" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="TR">
                    <p:cellEditor>

                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.messageTextTr}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{item.messageTextTr}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="EN">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.messageTextEn}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{item.messageTextEn}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="AR">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.messageTextAr}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{item.messageTextAr}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="KU">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.messageTextKu}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{item.messageTextKu}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:6%">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

mycontroller.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.api.UIData;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import tr.com.mergentech.web.devtool.controller.SessionController;
import tr.com.mergentech.web.devtool.dao.messages.IMessageFileDetailDao;
import tr.com.mergentech.web.devtool.entity.messages.MessageString;

@ManagedBean(name = "messageFileDetailController")
@ViewScoped
public class MessageFileDetailController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8484010295744327677L;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{messageFileDetailDao}")
    private IMessageFileDetailDao messageFileDetailDao;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionController}")
    private SessionController sessionController;

    public MessageFileDetailController() {
    }

    public IMessageFileDetailDao getMessageFileDetailDao() {
        return messageFileDetailDao;
    }

    public void setMessageFileDetailDao(
            IMessageFileDetailDao messageFileDetailDao) {
        this.messageFileDetailDao = messageFileDetailDao;
    }

    public SessionController getSessionController() {
        return sessionController;
    }

    public void setSessionController(SessionController sessionController) {
        this.sessionController = sessionController;
    }

    public List<MessageString> getFileDetailList() throws Exception {
        return getMessageFileDetailDao().getMessageFileDetail(
                sessionController.getMessageFile());
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws Exception {
    MessageString message = ((MessageString) (event.getObject()));
        System.out.println(message.getId() + " -  "
                + message.getMessageTextEn() + " -  "
                + message.getMessageTextKu());
        getMessageFileDetailDao().update(message, message.getId());
    }



}
```

mylog file:

```
2014-07-17T16:15:41.642+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:15:41.690+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.771+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.791+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.804+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.830+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.841+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.857+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.868+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.882+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.895+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.905+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.915+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.924+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.932+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.944+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.954+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.965+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:42.973+0300|Info: 6 -  Department of Expenditure Input -
2014-07-17T16:16:42.981+0300|Info: Hibernate: select messagestr0_.ID as ID1_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING messagestr0_ where messagestr0_.ID=?
2014-07-17T16:16:43.123+0300|Info: Hibernate: update MESSAGE_STRING set MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?, MESSAGE_TEXT_AR=?, MESSAGE_TEXT_EN=?, MESSAGE_TEXT_KU=?, MESSAGE_TEXT_TR=?, MESSAGE_TITLE=? where ID=?
2014-07-17T16:16:43.138+0300|Info: Hibernate: select messagestr0_.ID as ID1_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, messagestr0_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING messagestr0_ where messagestr0_.ID=?
2014-07-17T16:16:43.162+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:43.175+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:52.334+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
2014-07-17T16:16:52.352+0300|Info: Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID as MESSAGE_2_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_AR as MESSAGE_3_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_EN as MESSAGE_4_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_KU as MESSAGE_5_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TEXT_TR as MESSAGE_6_3_0_, this_.MESSAGE_TITLE as MESSAGE_7_3_0_ from MESSAGE_STRING this_ where (this_.MESSAGE_FILE_ID=?) order by this_.MESSAGE_TITLE asc
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not about primefaces row editing. I looked and tested your xhtml codes and worked properly. **You are getting 'RowEditEvent event' object values properly**. So Maybe your problem is in your dao packages and may not commit the changes to database. there is no problem in Jsf page and class.

Comment: I'm sorry,"|Info: 6 -  Department of Expenditure Input - " writes in console,when I tested code. Because when I edit the row, comes from the old data.